Quantum error correction references
I would like to understand more about QEC, such as surface codes, error codes, and qLDPC codes.
For quantum algorithms beyond the Nielsen and Chuang book the lecture notes by Andrew Childs are a very good resource, and I'm looking for something similar for quantum error correction.
Do you have something similar for QEC to recommend/you found useful in understanding the subject?

I'm converting this to Community wiki so that others can share resources that they've found useful.
General QEC references
Gottesman's textbook: Gottesman is writing a textbook and releasing some of the chapters periodically. Textbook
Waterloo IQC course (2024): Debbie Leung and Michael Vasmer taught a QEC course, the parts for LDPC code were pretty informative. Lecture notes, videos.
Waterloo IQC course (2018): Gottesman and Yoshida recorded a lecture series taught while Gottesman was still at Perimeter Institute. Lecture videos

$^\dagger$10/17/2024 Converted to Community wiki. Original header: "Biased sample based on my affiliations. I've used all of these resources and liked them." 

These are very good resources, thank you!

Here is a zoo for error correction codes.
https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/
In particular it contains (what should be a near to all known) quantum references.
